# Page Viewer Web Part will not work when i access my SharePoint sites using https

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, iframe, page-viewer-web-part

I am working on sharepoint server 2013 web application. and i added a Page viewer Web part which is showing an external system. the url for the external system is (`http://HRWebApplication`).
now when i access my sharepoint web application using `http` with sharepoint server name as follow `http://SPservername/` the page viewer worked well.

but if i access my sharepoint web application using `HTTPS` + I used an alternative access name such as `https://OurSharePointIntranet.intra` the page viewer will not show the external system instead a white page will be rendered.
so can anyone adivce what can be causing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Page Viewer webpart is nothing more than an IFRAME. loading HTTP content in an HTTPS site is a security risk so it is not allowed. 
You can try adding a HTTPS proxy, or a using IIS URL Rewriting on the target HRWebApplication machine to "trick" the SharePoint site and load the HTTP content through that.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site).

Comment: thanks for in the info , now modifying the external system itslef or the deplyed site on IIS is not a way to do in our case.. so what i can do from a sharepoint side to handle this ? is there a way to allow loading http content under https from a sharepoint-side?

Comment: It's not SharePoint, it's the browser. Loading HTTP content in an HTTPS secured site breaks security. PS, you would not be modifying the external site, buut add a HTTPS redirect site next to it with IIS URL Rewriting. The site itself would stay intact. The process used is SSL Offloading using Application Request Routing,
An in-depth article on this can be found here:
http://rdingwall.com/2013/09/24/howto-set-up-an-ssl-offload-termination-proxy-with-iis-7/

Comment: Add empty site, add the following web.config (after installing ARR)
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:80/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="Rewrite" path="*" verb="*" modules="RewriteModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>